Probability distribution for measuring any operator from Wigner function
Let $\hat{A}$ be an operator and $W(\mathbf{q})$ the Wigner function of a state, where $\mathbf{q}=(x,p)$ is a point in phase space. Then if $A$ is the function on phase space which is the Wigner-Weyl transform of $\hat{A}$, we may compute the expectation of $\hat{A}$ as $$\left\langle \hat{A}\right\rangle=\int _{ }^{ }A\left(\mathbf{q}\right)W\left(\mathbf{q}\right)d\mathbf{q}.$$
Now, if $\hat{A}=\hat{x}$ (or $\hat{p}$), we can do better. We can actually find the probability distribution for measuring $\hat{x}$ by integrating out $p$ in the Wigner function. I'm wondering if there is a generalization of this to find the probability distribution for measuring $\hat{A}$. If the Wigner function were really a probability distribution, this could be done as $$P\left(m\right)=\int _{ }^{ }\delta \left(A\left(\mathbf{q}\right)-m\right)W\left(\mathbf{q}\right)d\mathbf{q},$$ where $P(m)$ give the probability density for achieving $m$ when measuring $\hat{A}$. This means that $\int _{m_1}^{m_2}P(m)dm$ is the probability of measuring a value between $m_1$ and $m_2$ if one measures $\hat{A}$. Is this true? If it is, could someone provide a citation for this result that I could put in a paper? Thanks in advance.

Yup, those equations are true. I'm not sure I understand your second sentence. Could you clarify?

In your notation,
$$\left\langle \hat{A}\right\rangle=\int _{ }^{ }A\left(\mathbf{q}\right)W\left(\mathbf{q}\right)d\mathbf{q}  \\  = \int _{ }^{ }\!\! dm d\mathbf{q}   ~ W\left(\mathbf{q}\right) \delta \left(A\left(\mathbf{q}\right)-m\right) m, 
$$
so you may define
$$P\left(m\right)=\int\!\! d\mathbf{q}~\delta \left(A\left(\mathbf{q}\right)-m\right) W\left(\mathbf{q}\right),$$
s.t.
$$
\int\!\! dm~ P(m) ~m = \left\langle \hat{A}\right\rangle
$$
with $\int\!\! dm~ P(m) =1$ by consideration of the identity operator.

$P(m)$ is not positive-semidefinite. So not a bona-fide probability.

You may see this by considering the first excited state of the oscillator in polar coordinates, $x^2+p^2\equiv \hbar z\geq 0$, i.e.,
$W_1(z)= -e^{-z} (1-2z)$, and $A(z)=z$, hence
$P(m)= -e^{-m}(1-2m)$, which changes sign at $m=1/2$.

I want to know whether $P(m)$ can regarded as an honest probability density in the sense that $\int _{m_1}^{m_2}P(m)dm$ is the probability of measuring a value between $m_1$ and $m_2$ if one measures $\hat{A}$. According to your statement that $P(m)$ may not be positive-semidefinite, this would appear to be false, but I would appreciate an example to prove your assertion.

It looks like you are missing a factor of $m$ in the integrals of the second line. But I don't understand how that would then follow from the first line.

Thanks, fixed now.
